# Oracle SQL query to find special characters for phone numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a query to find special character for phone numbers.

Expected phone number is : `2047653894`

Actual: `204765389(4`, `204-7653894`, `-2047653894`, `(204)7653894`, `20476+53894`, ....

NOTE: I only want to find the phone numbers with special characters. I don't want to replace special characters.

Comment: Have a look at REGEXP_REPLACE(). https://erp-integrations.com/2017/08/31/how-to-replace-special-characters-in-oracle-sql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can use regular expressions, they are slow and it may be faster to use simple string functions and use `TRANSLATE` to find all the non-numeric characters and then replace them:

```sql
SELECT TRANSLATE(
         phone_number,
         '0' || TRANSLATE(phone_number, 'x0123456789', 'x')
         '0'
       ) AS simplified_phone_number
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (phone_number) AS
  SELECT '204765389(4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '204-7653894' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '-2047653894' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '(204)7653894' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '20476+53894' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| SIMPLIFIED_PHONE_NUMBER |
| --- |
| 2047653894 |
| 2047653894 |
| 2047653894 |
| 2047653894 |
| 2047653894 |

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c44a5/2)

---

#### Update

If you want to list phone numbers with non-digit characters then you can also use `TRANSLATE` to remove the digits and check if there are any other characters:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  TRANSLATE(phone_number, 'x0123456789', 'x') IS NOT NULL
```

you could also use `REGEXP_LIKE` to check that the string is not entirely digits:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  NOT REGEXP_LIKE(phone_number, '^\d+$')
```

or that there are non-digits:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(phone_number, '\D')
```

However, regular expressions are probably going to be slower than simple string functions like `TRANSLATE`.

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/afc01/5)

Comment: I just want to list phone numbers with special characters. I don't want to replace them

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to *remove* all non-digits (here, where I live, phone numbers are *digits only*; I'm not talking about various formats phone numbers might have):

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '204765389(4'  from dual union all
  3     select '204-7653894'  from dual union all
  4     select '-2047653894'  from dual union all
  5     select '(204)7653894' from dual union all
  6     select '20476+53894'  from dual
  7    )
  8  select
  9    col,
 10    regexp_replace(col, '\D') result
 11  from test;

COL          RESULT
------------ ------------------------------------------------
204765389(4  2047653894
204-7653894  2047653894
-2047653894  2047653894
(204)7653894 2047653894
20476+53894  2047653894

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT]**

If you just want to find phone numbers that contain anything but digits, use `regexp_like`:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '204765389(4'  from dual union all
  3     select '204-7653894'  from dual union all
  4     select '-2047653894'  from dual union all
  5     select '(204)7653894' from dual union all
  6     select '20476+53894'  from dual union all
  7     select '2047653897'   from dual
  8    )
  9  select col
 10  from test
 11  where regexp_like(col, '\D');

COL
------------
204765389(4
204-7653894
-2047653894
(204)7653894
20476+53894

SQL>
```

Comment: I don't want to replace special characters. I only want to list all phone numbers with special characters. I provided actual as examples. It can be any special characters.

Comment: I see; your sentence, saying "Expected phone number is ..." fooled me - I thought you want to remove anything but digits to get "valid" phone numbers. Have a look at edited answer, please.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[[:punct:]]` posix along with `REGEXP_REPLACE()` such as

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col,'[[:punct:]]') AS col
  FROM t
```

assuming each comma-separated value represents a column value within a table

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/S8pHrEUm)</kbd>